# How to make IDLE python display directly results from a function defined and ran from a .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, numpy

I have tried many set and search quite some time. I'll try to summarize to my problem.

I a have a file I name script.py.

Inside this script.py I have something like this:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from numpy import matrix

#Inserting variables:
A=float(input("insert position 1: "))
K=float(input("insert position 2: "))

#Doing some math:
a1=A*K
a2=A/K

#Defining a funtion:
def solve(var1,var2)
#This function uses numpy and math and handles matrices.
#I am not putting it to save space and make my problem clear

#Calling the funtion:
solve(a1,a2)
print (solve)
#The values of a1 and a2 are the once I calculated previously
```

Then I press "run module" to run script.py, it shows:

```
>> insert position 1:

>> insert position 2:
```

I insert the values and then it shows:

```
<function solve at 0x000000000A0C1378>
```

What can I do to make the python shell display the result directly?

Currently in order to get the results I need to type in the python shell

```
>> solve(a1,a2)
```

to have my result.

I hope I was able to make my problem clear and simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the function itself, not the output from the function call. To achieve this, either save the function output to a variable then print, or just print straight away.

1st Method:

```
ans = solve(a1,a2)
print(ans)
```

2nd Method:

```
print(solve(a1,a2))
```